# Methods to Analytically Solve a Nonlinear PDE

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, transformation, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm looking for suggestions to solve:
$$ u_t = u_{xxxx}-3u(u_x)^2-\frac{3}{2}u^2u_{xx}+\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}+F $$
where $F$ is currently an unknown function of unknown type (might be linear, exponential, etc.). Ignoring that ambiguity (pretend it vanishes), I am unsure of any method to solve such a PDE. I attempted separation of variables but that didn't help because of the nonlinearities. I then tried seeking a steady-state solution however that didn't lead to anything fruitful. After that, I tried using the $1$D and $2$D Fourier Transforms in space and space and time respectively but again that didn't really help. In this case, I got terms that involved self-convolutions of either $u$ or $u_x$ and this made the equation even harder to solve.

One last thought I had was to maybe use the Cole-Hopf Transform: i.e. introduce some new variable $w=\phi(u)$. In doing this, I started calculating partials of $w$ that would appear in my PDE and the expressions I got seemed even more complicated. This kind of leads me to believe that this won't be a fruitful avenue either, however, I have never really tried using this method so I am wondering if I'm maybe doing something wrong. Here I found:
$$ w_t = \phi'(u)u_t $$
$$ w_x = \phi'(u)u_x $$
$$ w_{xx} = \phi''(u)u_x^2+\phi'(u)u_{xx} $$
$$ w_{xxx} = \phi'''(u)u_x^3 + 3\phi''(u)u_xu_{xx}+\phi'(u)u_{xxx} $$
$$ w_{xxxx} = \phi^{(4)}(u)u_x^4 + 6\phi'''(u)u_x^2u_{xx}+3\phi''(u)u_{xx}^2+4\phi''(u)u_xu_{xxx}+\phi'(u)u_{xxxx} $$
Now I just don't really see how to use these equations to generate a simplified version of my original PDE or even how to definitively say that this won't help me in reducing the PDE. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Even if you do manage to find a "pencil and paper" solution, it will almost certainly be so long and unwieldy that it will be useless in practice. In contrast, the equation is totally integrable in $t$ - it is what's known as a time evolution equation, so numerical solutions are very easily constructed.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that an analytical solution exists? Only very special nonlinear PDEs have analytical solutions. As a first step you could try the [Painlevé Integrability Test](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2205371_The_Painleve_Integrability_Test). This gives necessary but not sufficient conditions for a PDE to be integrable. The test is cumbersome to do by hand but is manageable with computer algebra systems. I found some hits here https://www.swmath.org/?term=Painlev%C3%A9%20integrability that may be useful for you.

If your equation passes the Painlevé test, you'll need to look for a [Lax pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_pair). Note that one may not exist since the Painlevé property is necessary but not sufficient for integrability. See this [Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355308/lax-pair-of-an-integrable-non-linear-pde) for some suggestions.

You'll want to read up on [Integrable Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) if you're not familiar with the topic. It's been nearly 15 years since I've studied this area, but I recall *Introduction to Classical Integrable Systems* [1] by Babelon et al. being a nice read although I recall almost none of its contents.

[1] *Babelon, Olivier; Bernard, Denis; Talon, Michel*, [**Introduction to classical integrable systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511535024), Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 0-521-82267-X/pbk). xii, 602 p.(2003). [ZBL1045.37033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1045.37033).